# Import Excel data to SQL Server

Tags: ssis

What is the correct way of importing data from Excel 2007 file to SQL Server database 2008? The data from excel file should be transferred successfully even if the data in Excel file is changed / replaced with different data except the column name at first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is very finicky about how you remove rows from it.  Your best bet is to select all rows below the column headers and right click and delete.  If you simply clear contents and then don't paste in as many rows, it looks to SSIS like you have rows with nulls in them which sometimes causes the types of errors you are seeing.

Comment: But if other users/clients remove the rows without deleting, the error occurs. Once the package is deployed to another server, if the same problem occurs then there is no solution over there. But inside the BIDS, we can solve by refreshing the meta data.Is this product problem, where microsoft is still working on it ??

Comment: I did the same what you suggested. The same error occurs. Have you overcome with this ? Got any solution ?

Comment: If the users/clients are changing the schema, then automating this process using SSIS is not going to work. I am not sure MS will ever implement the ability for dynamic schemas. See this article: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35029554/dynamic-refresh-of-schema.aspx

Comment: Then I think we better go for Script Task. I think this will work using Script Task.